# Monaco Editor missing modules

Tags: monaco-editor

You can use the `monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib` to add any *.d.ts modules that you might need during the TypeScript parsing.

Is there some sort of callback to get a list of any modules it couldn't find during the parsing.  For example in this screen snap shot it can't resolve any of the modules.
[image: Module resolution error]

Is there some way either during parsing (so I can dynamically load) or after parsing that I can get an array of these files that it can't resolve so that I can use the addExtraLib to resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say no as is as it ends here: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/worker.ts#L70 : it looks for the model - but there are no callback/event to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that down, I believe you are correct.